# How to change shape from (10,50) into (10,)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So my matrix A shape is (10,) and matrix B shape is (10,50). How can I change my matrix B shape from (10,50) into (10,) so that I can subtract it with my matrix A?

Comment: You should include a bit more information. To be specific, what are you using as the inputs ```X```, ```y```, and ```theta``` in your example? I see someone has given an example of using ```None```, although I'm not sure if that would work as expected (at least I can't test it with your example as is) and I would probably recommend adding ```np.newaxis``` into ```theta``` instead, depending on your exact requirements. EDIT - I've just seen ```np.newaxis``` is an alias for ```None```, but my comments about more detail in your question still stand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `theta` to a two-dimensional array (here shaped `(10, 1)`):

```
>>> theta[:,None] - gamma
```

Comment: I would have said us ```np.newaxis``` instead of ```None```, although a quick google has shown me they're equivalent, so I learned something today :) good answer